# Weird splitter issue

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, splitter

I borrowed a bit of code for a splitter bar in between two edits, but I'm getting weirdness when I try to either write on the bottom one or resize them by moving the bar. Often, the bottom edit disappears completely and the scrollbar dances around.

Ultimately, my goal is to have the window divided up into 5 different edits for a look similar to this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/Win32TreeList/TreeList.gif

Am I going about it the right way?

Relevant code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HINSTANCE   hInst;
    RECT        rect;
    static HCURSOR  hCursor;
    static BOOL bSplitterMoving;
    static DWORD    dwSplitterPos;
    static HWND hWnd1, hWnd2;

    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            hInst = ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance;

            hWnd1 = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                L"edit", NULL,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE | WS_VSCROLL,
                0, 0, 0, 0,
                hWnd, (HMENU)1,
                hInst, NULL);

            hWnd2 = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                L"edit", NULL,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE | WS_VSCROLL,
                0, 0, 0, 0,
                hWnd, (HMENU)2,
                hInst, NULL);

            hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_SIZENS));
            bSplitterMoving = FALSE;

            dwSplitterPos = 130;
```

//

```
    case WM_SIZE:
        if ((wParam != SIZE_MINIMIZED) && (HIWORD(lParam) < dwSplitterPos))
            dwSplitterPos = HIWORD(lParam) - 10;

        /* Adjust the children's size and position */
        MoveWindow(hWnd1, 0, 0, LOWORD(lParam), dwSplitterPos - 1, TRUE);
        MoveWindow(hWnd2, 0, dwSplitterPos + 2, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam) - dwSplitterPos - 2, TRUE);
        return 0;

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        if (HIWORD(lParam) > 10) // do not allow above this mark
        {
            SetCursor(hCursor);
            if ((wParam == MK_LBUTTON) && bSplitterMoving)
            {
                GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
                if (HIWORD(lParam) > rect.bottom)
                    return 0;

                dwSplitterPos = HIWORD(lParam);
                SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SIZE, 0, MAKELPARAM(rect.right, rect.bottom));
            }
        }
        return 0;

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        SetCursor(hCursor);
        bSplitterMoving = TRUE;
        SetCapture(hWnd);
        return 0;


    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        ReleaseCapture();
        bSplitterMoving = FALSE;
        return 0;
```

//

Images showing what's happening:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBDjt.jpg

Comment: If the scrollbar is dancing around it's because of error elsewhere. You should make a minimum working example (you have already posted most of the code, you might as well add WinMain etc.) For `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, put `SetCapture` before `SetCursor`

Comment: Not sure, why you observe the effect you see. There are several issues with your code, though. For one, do **not** use `HIWORD` when extracting data out of a [WM_MOUSEMOVE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645616.aspx) lParam. Use `GET_Y_LPARAM` instead. Also, when moving multiple windows simultaneously, have a look into [BeginDeferWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632672.aspx).

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the problem you describe with your code (with some additions to make it compile and call to `DefWindowProc`). Splitter behaves perfectly as intended. Did you try your own snip? It could be that it works for you as well, and the problem is in code you omitted. Please provide a minimum example and describe how exactly you reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks, all three of you. I'll upload the code and post it here soon. I'm sure now it's just something stupid I've done.

Comment: Here's the Pastebin for it. I really appreciate that you all are taking a look at it. I'd love to know what idiotic mistake I'm making! http://pastebin.com/2kx0S0tB

Answer (score 0):

A simple `WNDCLASSEX wcx` declaration will work sometimes, but sometimes it crashes the program.

You should always initialize structures with zero: **`WNDCLASSEX wcx = { 0 };`**

Another problem, you didn't handle `WM_COMMAND` properly, you have to return 0 or break when it is done:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case IDM_EXIT:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case IDM_ABOUT:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return 0;//** THIS WAS MISSING
}
```